# php mysql fetch records having parent Ids in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch the album types having photo or video. I don't need empty albums. Table stucture as follows

```
id  catID parentID   catName    type
1    1      0        location   album
2    2      0        color      album
3    3      1        USA        album
4    4      0        Illinois1  album 
5    4      3        Illinois   photo
6    5      3        Chicago    video
7    6      2        Black      photo
8    7      2        Red        photo
```

Here I want to fetch the rows which has child records. i.e Here `Id` 1,2 and 3  are set as `parentid` for `3,5,6,7,8`th  records. `ID 4` doesn't have child records. SO I want to fetch the records `Id 1,2,3`

I used the following query.

```
            select rm.* from media rm, media as tmp 
        inner join tmp on rm.id = tmp.parentID and (tmp.media_type = 'photo' OR tmp.media_type = 'video');
```

But its not working. As a result  I want to fetch the album types having photo or video. I don't need empty albums.

Please help me

Comment: have you tried to put "AND category IS NOT NULL",  instead of 'category' put the column that you want!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have somehow confused implicit and explicit join syntax.

Cleaning up your original query:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT rm.id,
        rm.catID,
        rm.parentID,
        rm.catName,
        rm.type
FROM media rm
INNER JOIN media tmp  
ON rm.id = tmp.parentID 
AND tmp.media_type IN ('photo', 'video')
```

The distinct is required to only return each parent once even if they have multiple child records.